# How do I move a CVS repository from one server to another and maintain history?

Tags: migration, cvs

I have a CVS repository on my local workstation. I've demonstrated to my employer that version control is a great idea. Alright! So now I want to migrate my CVS history from my local workstation onto a real server.

I have installed CVS on the server and it is working.

Now, can I just move my repository files? Or do I have to do some sort of import command?

I know I could just check the current codebase into the new CVS server, but that'd lose the history, right?

Comment: "CVS repo copy" first hit by our friend (namely Google): - http://www.solarorange.com/docs/cvs/repositorymove.html Another one: - http://saloon.javaranch.com/cgi-bin/ubb/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic&f=12&t=003488

Comment: If u got answer, please post it here

Answer (score 1):

just copy the files - there really isn't anything else to it (at least if source and destination OS are the same)

Answer (score -3):

I just migrated one last week.

We're using Subversion at work, and all I did was move the root Subversion directory from one machine to the other. Then when I installed the [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) on the new machine, I just chose the existing Subversion root that I ported rather than creating a new repository. It seamlessly maintained history and files.

I'm not sure how well this will work with other source control systems.